# How to write text then convert it in vectoriel with iTextSharp?

Tags: c#, itext

I have this code ;

```
ColumnText.ShowTextAligned(canvas, Element.ALIGN_CENTER, foo, 150, 495, 0);
```

Every thing is ok.

But my printer want all my words in vectoriel format how can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, your printing company wants "text converted to outlines", right? Some printing companies prefer this so that there's no worry about getting the wrong fonts in place and also to bypass font licenses. Unfortunately I don't believe that iTextSharp supports this. I think you're only option is to run the PDF through something like Adobe Illustrator or possibly Adobe Acrobat.